# Cloud Run Oauth Access to Google Drive

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-cloud-run

How do I grant a Cloud Run Service access to Google Drive? I know I have to grant the service account Oauth access, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: OAuth means user credentials or service account. You can authorize a service account to access Google Drive in the same way you would authorize another user to access Google Drive. However, edit your question to clearly state what you are trying to do. The word **access** means a lot of things. For example, do you plan to write code to upload files to Google Drive? Is Google Drive part of your Google Workplace account?

Comment: Have you tried sharing the Drive folder with the service account that is used in your Cloud Run service? (A service account has a valid email after all.) I suspect there might be "scope" issues due to Google Workspace. But here's an example of using Google Sheets from Cloud Run: https://github.com/ahmetb/sheets-url-shortener

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run uses a service account for authentication/authorization. We have option to specify a user-managed service account when deploying it, otherwise by default it will use the Compute Engine default service account(`PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`).

To access the Google Drive resources in Cloud Run, sharing the Google Drive file/folder to the Could Run service account with viewer access.